# How to partially change a file name in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
 function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {




  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var auditorFirmName = e.values[1];
  var auditorAddressLine1 = e.values [2];
  var auditorAddressLine2 = e.values[3];
  var auditorAddressLine3 = e.values[4];
  var auditorAddressLine4 = e.values [5];
  var dateOfLetterIssue = e.values[6];
  const template = "template";



  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("");
  var templateFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(auditorFirmName + ${template}, templateFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{Insert Auditor Firm name}}", auditorFirmName);
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 1}}", auditorAddressLine1);
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 2}}", auditorAddressLine2);
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 3}}", auditorAddressLine3);
  body.replaceText("{{Address Line 4}}",auditorAddressLine4);
  body.replaceText("{{Date}}",dateOfLetterIssue);

  doc.saveAndClose();

}
```

Currently the line `var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(auditorFirmName, templateFolder);` is creating a copy of the original doc with the file name of the *auditor firm* as I have requested. But what I would like to do is create a file name with the *auditor firm name* and *the wording template* for example. Or a fixed piece of text that is not a variable. E.g currently the file will save as John Smith Auditors where I want it to save as John Smith Auditors Template. Where John Smith stays as a variable but the word Template would always remain fixed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing this line `var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(auditorFirmName, templateFolder);` to this `var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(auditorFirmName + template, templateFolder);` and add a `const template="whatever words you want to add";` earlier in the file near the top. You could just add `+ "Template"` if you like but typically your needs tend to change so the use of a variable may be useful but it's up to you.  If I'm not understanding you question I apologize.

Comment: Hey @MetaMan thanks for the support. 

So have added exactly as you have state however getting an error saying SyntaxError : missing ) after arguement list line. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Please update the code in your question to the ways it has been modified

Comment: Updated, sorry if I sound dumb Im not really sure what im doing. Ive learnt this from a youtube tutorial and managed to copy the code from there.

Comment: Sorry I over complicated the solution my first time.

Comment: That's it perfect it's worked! Thank you so much